# Assigning the right Contact properties to a rigid surface, in the presence of Hydroelastic elements in the sim

Tags: drake

I have a setup where I have either assigned the hydroelastic (rigid/compliant) `<collision>` tag to respective SDF assets within my simulated workspace, or declared and registered appropriate collision geometries in script for simulation elements without specifying in SDF. However, on running the script I see that I am running into the following error.

```
Requested a contact surface between a pair of geometries without hydroelastic representation for at least one shape: a undefined Box with id 128 and a soft Cylinder with id 144
```

This corresponds to a request for the collision surface between a Hydroelastic element and the default iiwa table that comes packaged within `drake/examples/models/table/`. On going through the SDF, I see that the `collision` tags are present but hydroelastic options are missing.

My question is whether I need to declare separate `ProximityProperties`, `AddRigidHydroelasticProperties` and then assign these to the table?

Comment: This is not a Python problem but is related to your use of the Drake toolbox hence it should be directed to the Drake support resources.

Comment: I have solved this by changing the contact model to `hydroelastic_with_fallback`. Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: It's suitable to ask Drake programming questions here.  I think the only problem was that the tag was originally #python instead of #drake.  It looks like it's since been fixed.